# How to make a new form situation default for the reset button

Tags: html, forms, button, reset

I have a hidden form with empty fields. The form is displayed after a click and filled with values. Then, when you click the reset button, the form becomes empty again, which makes sense technically speaking, but it's unexpected behaviour from the point of view of the user.

Is there a way to "reset" the reset button, so that after filling the form with values, that situation becomes the default whereto the reset button will reset the form?

Comment: Why do the form fields have to be empty when they're hidden? If you give them a default value, the reset will apply them when reset is clicked.

Comment: The page contains rows reflecting records in a database. The user clicks one of the rows to edit the data in the form.

Answer (score 0):

trigger on click reset button Here I wrote a demo code for you. Try it

```js
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('#hiddenform').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id"hiddenform">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
  
  <textarea name="description" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
  
  
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
</form>

<form id"textform">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
  
  <textarea name="description" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: This is just a recreation of the default function of the reset button in jQuery. I think you have not understand my question?

Comment: yeah, can you explain more better your question?

Comment: 1. start with empty form - 2. fill form with some values - 3. make (somehow) the filled form the start situation - 4. make a change to a value - 5. click the reset button and the form should return to the start situation (filled with some values in step 2).